# looking for Theorem 3.22 of Cardinal functions in topology

Tags: general-topology, reference-request

read an article which uses Theorem 3.22 of "Cardinal functions in topology, ten years later". I searched  this book on internet but is not there. I searched it in my university library but isn't there either. Does any body know that it says this theorem? Than you!

Answer (score 4):

For the record, this is Math. Centre Tracts $123$. It is available as a PDF from the Institutional Digital Repository of CWI (Centrum Wiskunde & Informatica). The search page is [here](https://repository.cwi.nl/); the easiest search is to use the dropdown box for the **Name** field. A direct link to the PDF is [here](http://oai.cwi.nl/oai/asset/12982/12982A.pdf).

Answer (score 2):

I seem to recall a .pdf of this book being available from [István Juhász's web site](http://www.renyi.hu/~juhasz/), but the "publications" link doesn't appear to be working right now.

Anyway, here is the statement:

> If $\beta \mathbb{N}$ does not embed into a compact Hausdorff space $X$, then $\rho ( X ) \leq 2^{c(X)}$

where

- $\rho(X) = | \{ U \subseteq X : U\text{ is regular open} \} |$;
- $c(X) = \sup \{ |\mathcal{U}| : \mathcal{U}\text{ is a family of pairwise disjoint open subsets of }X \} + \omega$ is the *cellularity* of $X$.